# Azure functions deployment with wrong dotnet version

Tags: azure-functions, github-actions

I have a Github repository for a Azure Function project that i've been using for a few months now with multiple deployments to Azure. A few days ago, i tried to deploy the same repository to a new Azure Function App for a new client using the deployment center (as previously) but now, I get a wrong dotnet version variable on the workflow yml file and the action fails.

The thing is, v4.0 is not a supported value as per [this validation file](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/releases-index.json). As soon as I update the version to a known release, the workflow runs succesfully and the Azure Function App works as expected.

My previous workflow yml files generated with the correct dotnet version 3.1

Is this a bug or do I need to update the yml file and go on my merry way?

***Azure Function App Deployment Center***

[image: Azure Function App Deployment Center]

***Generated Github workflow yml file***

[image: Generated Github workflow yml file]

Answer (score 1):

Known the post been posted a year ago, for future searchers:

When YML is created through Azure, there is a bug at the moment.
Azure put in the Azure Function Version into the DotNet_Version field.

Change to your version, like this:

```
DOTNET_VERSION: '6.0.x'
```